# How to combine c11 and c99 compilers

Tags: gcc, makefile, solaris, c99, c11

I have a SPARC server with Solaris SPARC 10 OS installed

I am trying to compile source code from VLC media player and PHP 7 tarballs

However the stumbling block I encounter is that when I type in `./configure` into my PUTTY terminal the gcc compiler tells me halfway through configuration that it needs C99 compiler.

I know that this statement enables the c99 compiler

```
BUILDCC="/usr/bin/gcc -std=gnu99" ./configure
```

but by doing this I switch off the c11 compiler and so I cannot still complete a full configuration.

How do I switch on both C11 and C99 compilers and/or can I type in a command that will switch from one compiler to another whilst in the configuration process, as and when the gcc compiler needs to?

I thankyou for any feedback given

regards :)

Comment: What happens if you change `-std=gnu99` to `-std=gnu11`? A C11 compiler is, for most practical purposes, also a C99 compiler.

Comment: Are there binaries named `/usr/bin/c99` (the POSIX mandated name for a C99 compiler) and `/usr/bin/c11`?